# Can I use the torchaudio ctc_decoder on a hugging face pretrained Wav2Vec2ForCTC model to be quantized, scripted and optimized for mobile?

Tags: python, android, pytorch

I am experimenting with the PyTorch Android example app https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/SpeechRecognition and want to add beam search. It builds the model like so:

```
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h")
model = import_huggingface_model(model)
model.encoder.transformer.pos_conv_embed.__prepare_scriptable__()
model = model.eval()

class SpeechRecognizer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.labels = [
            "<s>", "<pad>", "</s>", "<unk>", "|", "E", "T", "A", "O", "N", "I", "H", "S",
            "R", "D", "L", "U", "M", "W", "C", "F", "G", "Y", "P", "B", "V", "K", "'", "X",
            "J", "Q", "Z"]

    def forward(self, waveforms: Tensor) -> str:
        logits, _ = self.model(waveforms)  # [batch, num_seq, num_label]
        best_path = torch.argmax(logits[0], dim=-1)  # [num_seq,]
        prev = ''
        hypothesis = ''
        for i in best_path:
            char = self.labels[i]
            if char == prev:
                continue
            if char == '<s>':
                prev = ''
                continue
            hypothesis += char
            prev = char
        return hypothesis.replace('|', ' ')

model = SpeechRecognizer(model)  # implements forward(self, waveforms: Tensor) -> str
quantized_model = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
    model, qconfig_spec={torch.nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.qint8)
scripted_model = torch.jit.script(quantized_model)
optimized_model = optimize_for_mobile(scripted_model)
optimized_model._save_for_lite_interpreter("wav2vec2.ptl")
```

`wav2vec2.ptl` is then copied to the Android app as an asset, and generates greedy search transcriptions using :

```
module = LiteModuleLoader.load(assetFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "wav2vec2.ptl"));
final String result = module.forward(IValue.from(inTensor)).toStr();
```

I want to add beam search, so I'm trying to apply this tutorial https://pytorch.org/audio/main/tutorials/asr_inference_with_ctc_decoder_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-asr-inference-with-ctc-decoder-tutorial-py for applying a beam search decoder.

It instantiates a beam search decoder using:

```
files = download_pretrained_files("librispeech-4-gram")
LM_WEIGHT = 3.23
WORD_SCORE = -0.26
beam_search_decoder = ctc_decoder(
    lexicon=files.lexicon,
    tokens=files.tokens,
    lm=files.lm,
    nbest=3,
    beam_size=1500,
    lm_weight=LM_WEIGHT,
    word_score=WORD_SCORE,
)
```

It is then passed the model emission directly.

Can I apply the beam search ctc_decoder on the former model to run on Android?

The signature of the greedy decoder decode method in the first tutorial is:

```
forward(self, waveforms: Tensor) -> str
```

This is built into a `.ptl` file and run on the mobile. I don't know how Python runs on Android.

The signature of the decode method in the beam search decoder generated by `ctc_decoder` in the second tutorial is:

```
__call__(
        self, emissions: torch.FloatTensor, lengths: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None
    ) -> List[List[CTCHypothesis]]
```

So I wrapped the decoder with an adaptor:

```
class SpeechRecognizer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model, decoder):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.decoder = decoder
    def forward(self, waveforms: Tensor) -> str:
        logits, _ = self.model(waveforms)  # [batch, num_seq, num_label]
        return self.decoder(logits)
```

But then when I run:

```
quantized_model = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
     model, qconfig_spec={torch.nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.qint8)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'torchaudio.lib.flashlight_lib_text_dictionary.Dictionary' object
```

Is this an entirely silly approach, and I should implement beam search natively in Java on device, working with the model emissions directly?

All feedback gratefully received.